# Spyder can't launch

Tags: crash, spyder, launch, anaconda3

My Spyder crashes while lauching it. It's never successfully opened

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/macbookair/.config/pylintrc'

Detailed Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/bin/spyder", line 11, in  sys.exit(main()) File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 252, in main mainwindow.main(options, args) File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 1956, in main mainwindow = create_window(MainWindow, app, splash, options, args) File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/utils.py", line 289, in create_window main.setup() File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 736, in setup internal_plugins = find_internal_plugins() File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/app/find_plugins.py", line 40, in find_internal_plugins mod = importlib.import_module(entry_point.module_name) File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "", line 1030, in _gcd_import File "", line 1007, in _find_and_load File "", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "", line 680, in _load_unlocked File "", line 850, in exec_module File "", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/plugin.py", line 22, in  from spyder.plugins.pylint.confpage import PylintConfigPage File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/confpage.py", line 16, in  from spyder.plugins.pylint.main_widget import (MAX_HISTORY_ENTRIES, File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/main_widget.py", line 35, in  from spyder.plugins.pylint.utils import get_pylintrc_path File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pylint/utils.py", line 16, in  import pylint.config File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pylint/config/__init__.py", line 27, in  from pylint.config.environment_variable import PYLINTRC File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pylint/config/environment_variable.py", line 11, in  PYLINTRC = find_pylintrc() File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pylint/config/find_default_config_files.py", line 94, in find_pylintrc for config_file in find_default_config_files(): File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pylint/config/find_default_config_files.py", line 76, in find_default_config_files if home_rc.is_file(): File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1456, in is_file return S_ISREG(self.st`your text`at().st_mode) File "/Users/macbookair/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1232, in stat return self._accessor.stat(self) PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/macbookair/.config/pylintrc'` 
Did anyone meet this problem too?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This problem will be fixed in Spyder 5.4.1, to be released before the end of 2022.